# How does parse.com push messages count towards the request limit?

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform

I have tried reading about requests/sec definition on the parse.com, but I still couldn't understand if push messages are considered a "request"?

I was wondering if I could use parse.com push services for free, even at 10 million push messages a month, as long as I don't pass the 1 million unique devices threshold?

How is it calculated within the free 30 requests/second, if at all?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A request to send a push does use an API request, and does count towards your burst limit.

However, that request could be to send a push to a single device, or a million devices, and it still uses just one request.

So yeah, you can get by for free with the limited scenario you described.